# Incorrect padding error while b64decoding

Tags: python, django

Hi I have following code which encodes and decodes certain data. But it gives me Incorrect Padding error while decoding data even when I have already added padding. The Code is;
**Encoding:**

```
    plain = str(data)
    mismatch = len(plain) % 16
    if mismatch != 0:
        padding = (16 - mismatch) * ' '
        plain += padding

    secret_key = '3216549874561230'  
    cipher = AES.new(secret_key, AES.MODE_ECB)
    encoded = base64.b64encode(cipher.encrypt(plain))
```

This encoded data is sent through a link. I am getting that data from ID parameter of my URL.
**Decoding:**

```
secret_key = '3216549874561230'
data = request.GET.get('ID')
cipher = AES.new(secret_key, AES.MODE_ECB)
decoded = cipher.decrypt(base64.b64decode(data))
print "-------------decoded-------------",decoded
data = {'id': decoded}
```

please help me I am new in it. And thank you so much guys already.

Comment: Can you give a [mcve] with a single block of code? Just set `plain` to a string literal instead of the code at the beginning. Also, how are you setting/getting the URL parameter?

Comment: Ok. Lets set data = 10. After this encoding I sent an email containing a URL like 127.0.0.1/reset-password/?ID='here comes the encoded value' and now I have accessed it which is shown in decoding part. In decoding part data contains encoded value.

Comment: How do you construct that URL? If you're using simple string concatenation/formatting/interpolation that's probably the issue. Base 64 has characters with a special meaning in URL parameters.

Comment: This is what I am creating and sending. 
TEXT = "Dear User," "\n \n   You recently requested to reset your password for your account.\n\n please click on below link.\n" + description + "?ID=" + encoded + " " + "\n\nThank You,\n XYZ Team"

description contains 127.0.0.1/reset-password/

Comment: Put `print(encoded)` and `print(data)` and see if they match up.

Comment: This is encoded value : encoded =  fIG+YkFHVHSib46tqREppw==
This is data in decoding block : data =  fIG YkFHVHSib46tqREppw==

Comment: By the way you probably shouldn't be implementing this kind of stuff yourself. Use a library like django-allauth.

Comment: Ok sure pal. Thank you very much. I will check that. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution to your problem is to not implement things like this yourself, especially since security is involved. Use a library such as [django-allauth](http://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/).

Your problem is putting a base 64 string directly into a URL where some of those characters have special meanings. In your example in the comments, the `+` is interpreted as a space when it's in a URL parameter. It needs to be escaped properly, e.g. `urlencode({'ID': 'fIG+YkFHVHSib46tqREppw=='})` gives `ID=fIG%2BYkFHVHSib46tqREppw%3D%3D` which will be interpreted correctly on the other side.